# pgfplots: Problem With Rotated Tick Label (`extra x tick` and normal `x tick` rotated differently)

Tags: pgfplots

- Maybe I do not see the obvious :).
- **I want to have an `extra x tick` that is NOT rotated.**
- **The normal `x ticks` must be rotated by 90°.**
- I also tried `extra x tick style = {rotate = -90},` which did not work as expected (the positioning got off).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {xlabel},
        ylabel = {ylabel},
        xtick = {0, 5},
        xticklabel style = {rotate = 90},
        extra x ticks = {2.5},
        extra x tick labels = {{Test}},
        extra x tick style = {rotate = 0},
    ]
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define extra tick label style. For example with `extra x tick style={tick label style={rotate=-90}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {xlabel},
        ylabel = {ylabel},
        xtick = {0, 5},
        xticklabel style = {rotate = 90},
        extra x ticks = {2.5},
        extra x tick labels = {Test},
        extra x tick style={tick label style={rotate=-90,anchor=north}}, % defined anchor is not necessary but it doesn't harm ;-)
    ]
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! Do you also consider this "weird"?

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner: *I* do not. The tick is the small line segment -it is not the label.

Answer (score 2):

You are rotating the `tick` 0 deg - you want to rotate the `label` 90 deg like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {xlabel},
        ylabel = {ylabel},
        xtick = {0,5},
        xticklabel style = {rotate = 90},
        extra x ticks = {2.5},
        extra x tick style={tick label style={rotate=-90}},
        extra x tick labels = {Test},
    ]
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with rotated label]

Comment: +1: Thx - stupid me!